# How to prevent notification bar from closing upon notification action click

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

In my app i have notification with pause/play action, however, when user clicks on the action, notification bar is closing. How can i prevent notification bar from closing upon action click?

Method which creates notifcation:

```
public void createNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, IntentActivity.class);
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent2, 0);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        Notification noti = builder
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Czas trwania: " + time + "\nKalorie: 4kcal"))
                .addAction(icon, actionString, pIntent2).build();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

change your code from

```
setAutoCancel(true)
```

to

```
setAutoCancel(false)
```

Comment: I think i didn't make my self clear, I want to prevent notification drawer from hiding upon action click. I need setAutoCancel(true) to dismiss notification when user clicks on it (on the notification not notification's action)

Comment: @user1852879 Try this.

Comment: I tried it and the drawer is still closing when i setAutoCancel(false), it only keeps the notification alive when user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem.

For every notification action used PendingIntent. It seems that if you create PendingIntent  from PendingIntent.getActivity(...) - it closes notification. If you create from PendingIntent.getService(...) or from PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) - notification remains.

So if you want to start activity from notification and don't hide notification: send intent to Service or send broadcast, then start activity from there.

But from there starts another problem: launched activity displays under notification and I don't know how to bring it to top.

Answer (score 0):

While building Notification by `NotificationBuilder` you can use `builder.setAutoCancel(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda late to the party but it might help others facing this topic.

As Anrimian pointed out, building [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) via `getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int)` **closes the notification panel upon action click** and there is not much you can do about it as far as i know, it's just how it works.

But building the `PendingIntent` with `getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int)` or `getService(Context, int, Intent, int)` does what you are looking for.

So let's say you build a `PendingIntent` as follows:

```
val playIntent = Intent("ACTION_PLAY_INTENT")
val requestCode = 1
val playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Then you need to add the `PendingIntent` to `NotificationCompat.Builder` with:

```
.addAction(icon, actionString, playPendingIntent)
```

In your activity you can declare a receiver like this:

```
private val playBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // parse your actions here...
    }
}
```

Finally you can register by:

```
registerReceiver(playBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter("ACTION_PLAY_INTENT"))
```

The result is that **you perform actions without closing the notification panel**.
I've tested this approach also with [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews) and works just fine.