# How to prevent notification bar from closing upon notification action click while using PendingIntent.getActivity. Part 2

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

So in my app i have notification with pause/play action,  when user clicks on the action, notification bar is closing. How can i prevent notification bar from closing upon action click?

I've already done `.setAutoCancel(false);`

**Here I've found a "problem":**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53476100/10766642

`PendingIntent.getActivity(...)` - it closes notification bar.

And yes, I have this lines too:

```
        PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, (int)(Math.random()), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn1, btn1);
```

**How can i prevent notification bar closing without using** `PendingIntent.getService(...)` or `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)` ?

Comment: I think you need foreground service instead.

Comment: Why are you opening an activity from the notification if you don't want the user to immediately be able to interact with that activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake in this activity I want to interact with notification UI - so in `onCreate` will be something like `setContentView(R.layout.some_view);` and then I want to change image resource, for example `btn1.setImageBitmap(...)` or something like this. How I can interact with UI while using `Service`?

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. Your activity's layout is completely independent from the notification's UI. You don't need an activity to do anything notification UI related, you can post a notification from any type of component.